# Why use Array.prototype.slice.call with arguments

Tags: javascript

I am calling a method using apply and I do not know how many arguments I will be passing:

At the moment my code looks like this:

```
selectFolder: function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  this.addSelectedClass.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
},
```

The only reason  I am using Array.prototype.slice is because it is in most examples.

Why would I not just pass arguments like this:

```
 this.addSelectedClass.apply(this, arguments);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### `arguments` with `apply()` are fine

When calling `apply` on a function it's ok to just use original `arguments`. SO in your example you can easily replace the line with this one:

```
this.addSelectedClass.apply(this, arguments);
```

### `arguments` with `call()` are not fine

But if you'd be calling `call` then you should convert `arguments` to an actual array (which is done by a `slice()` call) if you'd want to pass your function an array of arbitrary objects/values. That's why `call()` is usually used when you know exactly the number of arguments you'd want to pass and pass them individually.

`arguments` are **not an actual array** object. They seem to be (have `length` property for instance), but they're not.

[Arguments on Mozilla Deveveloper Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments)

### A bit of explanation to make it completely clear

Documentation related to `apply()` and `call()` looks like this:

```
func.apply(thisArg[, argsArray]);
func.call(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]]);
```

We may execute the same function using any of these.

1. When using `apply()` we can pass all arguments at once. `slice()` is usually used to omit a particular argument from the call or to convert `arguments` to actual array.
2. When using `call()` we pass individual arguments and as many as we need to. If we'd provide arguments converted to an array, our called function would get one parameter of type array with all arguments supplied in that particular array.

I hope this clears thing up even more.

Comment: `.call()` accepts a list of arguments, not an array. `.apply()` accepts an array.

Comment: @MisterJack, `apply` can take any *"array-like"* object, e.g.: `(function (a, b) { return a+b; }).apply(this, {0:5, 1:10, length:2}); // 15`

Comment: What I meant is that `call` should be used as `foo.call(this, 'aa', 2)` (a list) and not like `foo.call(this, ['aa', 2])` because with a declaration like `function foo(a, b) {}` the latter example will have an array as the first parameter, and `undefined` as the second parameter.

Comment: @MisterJack: You're of course correct. I edited my answer to make it completely clear that you can still provide arguments as an array to `call()` but the function would get them as a single argument of type array. That's what the confusion related to your comment was all about. Hence I added more information to make it more clear.

Answer (score 3):

Because `arguments` is not an array. Running `Array.prototype.slice` makes it a normal array with functions like `map` and `forEach`. Basically anything in `Array.prototype`. `arguments` is, without this, just an object with a `length` property.

In your particular case, passing just `arguments` would probably work.

Comment: i think you meant "because arguments is not an array"